# Performing "atomic" operation "IncreaseIf" on database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, transactions, atomic

I need to perform *atomic* operation check value of some field of some entity framework model and increase it if its value is 0.

I thought about transactions, sth like:

```
bool controlPassed = false;
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    var model = ...ModelEntities.first_or_default(...)
    if (model.field == 0){
        ++model.field;
        ...saveChanges();
        controlPassed = true;
    }
    scope.Complete();
}
if (controlPassed)
{
    ...
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        --model.field;
        ...saveChanges();
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Of course, everything in try catch and so on.

My question is: how would it work?

It is really hard to check.
I have multithreaded application.

Is there a possibility, that two or more threads would pass control (check that `field == 0` and increase it)?

Whout would be blocked in database (database, table, row, field)?

I can't let two or more threads to be in `controlPassed` section simultaneously.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there a possibility, that two or more threads would pass control
>   (check that field == 0 and increase it)?

You have `Serializable` transaction (that is default for `TransactionScope`). It means that there can be two threads with field == 0 but immediately after that deadlock happens because transaction for the first thread holds a shared lock on the filed and transaction for the second thread holds another shared lock for the same field. Neither of these transaction can upgrade the lock to exclusive to save changes because they are blocked by shared lock in other transaction. I think same would happen for `RepeatableRead` isolation level.

If you change isolation level to `ReadCommitted` (the default for `SaveChanges`without `TransactionScope` when using MS SQL Server) the answer will be again yes but this time without deadlock because EF uses normal selects without any table hints - that means that no lock on record is held when select completes. Only save changes (modification) locks records until transaction commits or rolls back.

To lock record in `ReadCommitted` transaction with select you must use native SQL query and `UPDLOCK` (to lock record for update during select and held it until transaction ends) table hint. EF queries do not support table hints.

**Edit:** I wrote [a long article about pessimistic concurrency](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2012/09/entity-framework-and-pessimistic-concurrency) which describes why your solution doesn't work and what must be changed to make it work correctly.

Comment: I got an idea to prepare some tests: `n` threads, each entering scope, sleeping (to get all of them in scope), each getting some model from db, checking if field=null, if so then sleeping again and trying to save changes. I got results that it takes some time (for 10 s. it took ~15s) and exactly one thread is passing control. I think EF is trying to resolve deadlock. Do you know anything about it.

Comment: No it is most probably because you never got concurrent execution inside the critical section. I have an example to demonstrate it but I decided to write an article about this instead of posting another long update into my answer. I will finish the article within one or two days and let you know.

Comment: I'm quite sure I had concurrent execution there. All threads was doing all operations almost together and then sleep, so all of them was in the same section of code all the time. But Ill be waiting for your article, thanks a lot.

Comment: I added link to promised article.